# Custom Price for a specific product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

In Woocommerce, I would like to apply custom price for a specific product.

This is my actual code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_get_price','change_price_regular_member', 10, 2);
function change_price_regular_member($price, $productd){
    return '1000';
}
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook `woocommerce_get_price` is outdated and deprecated in Woocommerce 3 *(and it was a **filter hook** but NOT an action hook)*. It has been replaced by `woocommerce_product_get_price`.

So instead try this *(where you will define your targeted Product ID in this hooked function)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price','change_price_regular_member', 10, 2 );
function change_price_regular_member( $price, $product ){
    // HERE below define your product ID
    $targeted_product_id = 37;

    if( $product->get_id() == $targeted_product_id )
        $price = '1000';

    return $price;
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. just replace id of product `3030`

```
add_action('woocommerce_get_price','change_price_regular_member', 10, 2);
function change_price_regular_member($price, $productd){
    if($productd->id==3030){
        $price= 1000;
    }
    return $price;
}
```